# Can a HTTP/HTTPS server be hosted on the port which was opened after TCP hole punching?

Tags: http, web, tcp, p2p, hole-punching

Let us consider scenario where client A is behind NAT A and client B is behind NAT B. TCP hole punching happens which open a port on both the sides for communication. Can Client A host a http/https server on the open port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP hole punching works only for the specific TCP connection which can be established because a) both sides somehow know the source port of the peer up-front and b) start a TCP handshake with the peer at the same time. Only then a NAT state is established which is also only valid for this specific connection (source IP,port and destination IP,port).

An external client will not match the existing NAT state because source IP,port do not match the existing state. A new state will also not be created from inside just because there is some web server listing. So while the web server could be hosted behind the NAT it will not be reachable from outside the NAT.

Comment: In that case, once a connection is established between 2 peers, can 'peer 2' send a manual http request over the established tcp connection to 'peer1', and 'peer 1' handles the http request and send a manual http response to 'peer 2' ? Is this possible?

Comment: @MukeshKumar: Once the TCP connection is established it is possible to send anything over it, including HTTP requests and responses. But a normal web server will not work over an established connection, so there need to be a special web server or some "relay" which translates by reading the request, sending it to the real web server and reading the response, and then sending the response back to the remote client.